# (Android Studio) Problemas com OnRestart comendo a interface principal

Tags: java, android

Ao invés de o app mostrar a interface abaixo, ele puxa o método OnRestart direto e exibe "Programa reiniciado" quando abro o app. Como faço para corrigir isso ?
[image: ProblemaOnRestart]

Código :

```
TextView tInforme;
EditText tValor;
Button btDescobrir;
protected static final String CATEGORIA = "Exercicio";

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(CATEGORIA, getClassName() + ".onCreate()) chamado: " + savedInstanceState);
    TextView t = new TextView(this);
    t.setText("Programa reiniciado");
    setContentView(t);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercicio1);
    tInforme = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tInforme);
    tValor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tValor);
    btDescobrir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btDescobrir);}
    public void setbtDescobrir(View v) {

        String guessStr = tValor.getText().toString();
        int theGuess = Integer.parseInt(guessStr);
        int tValor = theGuess%2;
        if (tValor == 0){
            AlertDialog alertDialog;
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("O número é : ");
            alertDialog.setMessage("O número é par !");
            alertDialog.show();
        }
        else if (tValor == 1){
            AlertDialog alertDialog;
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("O número é : ");
            alertDialog.setMessage("O número é ímpar !");
            alertDialog.show();
        }





}

@Override
    public void OnRestart()
    {
        super.onRestart();
        Log.i(CATEGORIA, getClassName() + ". onRestart() chamado.");
    }
    private String getClassName()
{
    String s = getClass().getName();
    return s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("."));}
```

}

Comment: Se esse `OnRestart()` não está fazendo nada, porque ele está ai?

Comment: O objetivo é fazer com que quando ele for chamado, ele mostre na tela que o programa foi reiniciado, como um aviso. Daí em vez disso, ele está aparecendo direto na tela sem deixar que a interface do programa apareça, ficando em segundo plano

Comment: Isso acontece porque o seu OnRestart não faz nada (na verdade faz, que é apenas gerar um log, mas você só vai ver no logcat do Android Studio), enquanto que o método OnCreate é chamado sempre, independente de ser a primeira execução do app ou se ele já estava rodando, por isso você vai ver sempre a mensagem "Programa reiniciado"

Comment: Hmm, então acho que é um problema de relocar essa parte do "programa reiniciado" daí...

Comment: @MárcioOliveira eu disse não faz nada tão relevante... a principio não tinha visto algo que comprometesse o funcionamento. É importante o Paulo dar uma olhada no [ciclo de vida de uma atividade](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html?hl=pt-br).

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada. Sou iniciante e to tomando um pau massa pra mexer nisso, obg

Comment: Na verdade, eu fiz uma confusão. O OnCreate é chamado apenas na primeira vez que o app é executado, depois é que vem a chamada para o OnStart. O OnRestart só roda quando o app é colocado em background e depois retornado para o primeiro plano (antes de ser destruído).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que o problema está ligado a esta parte do código.

```
setContentView(t);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercicio1);
```

Pois você esta colocando como sua view principal o:

```
 TextView t = new TextView(this);
t.setText("Programa reiniciado");
```

Mesmo você chamando o

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercicio1);
```

Não vai funcionar pois ele desenha somente o primeiro setContentView. Acredito que o correto a se fazer é remover esta linha:

```
setContentView(t);
```

Comment: Acho que corrigi aqui, a tela não está ficando em segundo plano mais, obrigado